# How to link a renewed UK passport to Australian visa

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, australian-residents

I have just renewed my UK passport and it is now not linked with my Australian visa. I live in Australia.
I have tried to tell home affairs but unable to get through.
Does anyone know if it is possible to link the visa and UK passport yourself.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Australian Immigration page [Your passport details have changed](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/passport-details):

> You can tell us about changes in your passport details in two ways.
>
> ### Applied online
>
> Select 'Update details' > 'Change of passport details' in [ImmiAccount](https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login).
>
> Not all details can be updated online in ImmiAccount such as changes to date of birth or gender.
>
> ### Applied on paper or unable to update online
>
> If you applied on paper or can't update your details online, complete [Form 929 - Change of address and/or passport details form (172KB PDF)](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/form-listing/forms/929.pdf).